# Webdriver: ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOf is not working. Always throws an exception

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I'm using `ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOf` to check the invisibility of one of the element, but every time it throws the timeout exception for :

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOf(elementTobeInvisible));
```

Error Message:

```
org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for invisibility of Proxy element for: DefaultElementLocator 'By.xpath: //button[text()='button text']' (tried for 30 second(s) with 500 MILLISECONDS interval)
```

I've checked visibility of same element using `element.isDisplayed()` it returns 'false' correctly.

Recently I upgraded selenium from 2.53.0

- Webdriver: 3.7.1 or 3.6.0
- Chrome:  62.0.3202.94 (Official Build) (64-bit)
- OS: Windows 7

Comment: Did your Question get resolved? Eles show us the code & relevant HTML

Comment: yup. See my answer. Seems like selenium bug. For time being, I wrote an custom method that catches everything as an Exception and its working.

Comment: Using the core Exception from user level is not a good practice. We should try proper usage of the implementation only.

Comment: @DebanjanB: yes you are correct. I've changed my code to catch only required exceptions, not the core 'Exception'.

Answer (score 2):

Investigated the issue, looks like wrong implementation:

For version 2.53.0 and 3.7.0, there is implementation difference for invisibility method.

**2.53** Implementation:

```
public static ExpectedCondition<Boolean> invisibilityOfAllElements(final List<WebElement> elements) {
    return new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
        public Boolean apply(WebDriver webDriver) {
            Iterator var2 = elements.iterator();

            while(var2.hasNext()) {
                WebElement element = (WebElement)var2.next();

                try {
                    if (element.isDisplayed()) {
                        return false;
                    }
                } catch (Exception var5) {
                    ;
                }
            }

            return true;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return "invisibility of all elements " + elements;
        }
    };
}
```

Observation: Look at line "catch (**Exception** var5) ". Here we are catching everything as an Exception

---

for **3.7.1** implementation

```
public static ExpectedCondition<Boolean> invisibilityOfAllElements(final List<WebElement> elements) {
    return new ExpectedCondition() {
        public Boolean apply(WebDriver webDriver) {
            return Boolean.valueOf(elements.stream().allMatch((x$0) -> {
                return ExpectedConditions.isInvisible(x$0);
            }));
        }

        public String toString() {
            return "invisibility of all elements " + elements;
        }
    };
}


private static boolean isInvisible(WebElement element) {
    try {
        return !element.isDisplayed();
    } catch (StaleElementReferenceException var2) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Observation: We are only catching **StaleElementReferenceException**, hence while using the method throws **TimeoutException** which is not catched

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the below line of code instead of that -

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(elementTobeInvisible));
```

Or you can simply call the method like this -

```
//Wait until Invisibility of element is completed
public void waitForInvisibility(By byElement){
try{
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 120);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(byElement));
//May apply thread sleep for 1 or 2 seconds
}catch(Exception e){}}
```

Before call this method, declare the param By element like below -

```
By byElement = By.cssSelector("Use the element's css selector here");
```

//or

```
By byElement = By.xpath("Use the element's XPath here");
```

Comment: what's the type of the button? if the type of the button is button then simply can use By.cssSelector("button[type='button']"). For another type of the button you just change the type inside the single quotation.